# Android: PDF files hidden despite setting the MIME type

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, mime-types, android-intent-chooser

This is my Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/* , application/pdf, image/*");
```

But, when the file explorer shows up, the PDF files are grayed out i.e., un-choosable. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using minimum Android version 19 then you can do this below way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent .setType("*/*");
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
intent.setType("text/*|application/pdf|image/*");
```

Comment: Tried it, still see the PDF files greyed out